# Change the color of disabled textbox in IE

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I need to change the color of the disabled textbox value in my gridview to black.
It's working in every browser except IE.How to change the color of the text which is disabled

Comment: Could you give some examples of what you have tried?

Comment: are you talking about the font color?

Comment: .grid> tbody > tr > td input:disabled
        {
            color: black !important;   
        }

Comment: yes .I am talking about text color

Comment: Update (edit) your question with your current approach.

Answer (score 1):

It is not working in Internet Explorer because you simply can not change the font color of a disabled textbox in Internet Explorer.

However you can change ‘disabled’ to ‘readonly’ then use styling to reproduce whatever shaded disabled effect you want. ‘readonly’ controls are not turned into OS-level-disabled widgets giving you more latitude to style them. But when you do this you should remember that using the disabled attribute causes the underlying  element not to be submitted during a form submit but readonly controls are submitted to the server. So you should not use readonly if your server code isn't expecting a value from that control.